# MongoDB service wont start in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

Error I get is:

"New main PID 469 does not belong to service, and PID is not owned by root. refusing."

I am running this on a centos 7 docker container.

I have already double checked that all files are owned by mongod.

/var/lib/mongo is owned by mongod and so is /var/run/mongodb.

I have tried deleting the mongod.lock file but that does not fix it.

I have tried setting up another container with port 27017 open and it still fails.

The mongodb.pid file was not initially created. I created it but the service still fails.

Comment: Please show your error here in the question.

Comment: "I am running this on a centos 7 docker container" - Please post your Dockerfile. Let us take a look

Comment: The error is in the picture in the link. it just pulls up the picture.

Comment: I am not using a docker container. I will admit I am new to docker and am setting up a container with out one as of right now. I am going into the docker with a shell to build the tool I need running inside of it.

Comment: use plain text and don't post screenshots especially with logs

Comment: Look at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log - search for the error condition - usually this is close to the end of the file.